# Arch: tint2conf - gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

Tags: arch-linux, gtk

I have new laptop with Arch Linux, but can't start `tint2conf` in usual way - after launch it produce bunch of errors for each `.tint2rc` found, like:

> ```
> (tint2conf:3813): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
> snapshot NULL : tint2 -c '/home/setevoy/.config/tint2/MY-horizontal-dark-transparent.tint2rc' -s '/tmp/tint2-3813.jpg' 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
> ```

I have `gdk-pixbuf2` and `Imlib` installed on both boxes:

```
$ pacman -Q| grep 'gdk\|imlib'
gdk-pixbuf2 2.36.1+31+gecea71eb6-1
imlib 1.9.15-15
imlib2 1.4.9-1
```

`tint2` works well on the old box, and I found that on the new box - it won't use `gdk-pixbuf2` libs at all:

```
$ lsof -p 18020 | grep pix
tint2conf 18020 setevoy  mem       REG              254,0   686856    423644 /usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0.34.0
tint2conf 18020 setevoy  mem       REG              254,0   159536    424850 /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.3601.0
```

And results from an old laptop:

```
$ lsof  -p 609 | grep pix
tint2conf 609 setevoy  mem       REG              254,0    23104   166360 /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-jpeg.so
tint2conf 609 setevoy  mem       REG              254,0    43560   166901 /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libpixmap.so
tint2conf 609 setevoy  mem       REG              254,0   686856   159763 /usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0.34.0
tint2conf 609 setevoy  mem       REG              254,0   159536   166347 /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.3601.0
```

What can be wrong here? `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, something similar?

Arch + Openbox + Tint2.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears if you have compiled `gdk-pixbuf` with dynamic modules at runtime, but it can't find a required loader where it expects to find it. It can happen if you statically linked gdk-pixbuf into your application but didn't ship the loader files.

Best solution is to recompile gdk-pixbuf with all loaders embedded into the library:

```
./configure --disable-modules --with-included-loaders=yes
```